# Help with proof that nonempty set of integers bounded above has a max

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Can I get some feedback?I am studying this proof and am having trouble interpreting it.

Question:

Let $U= \mathbb{Z}$ Prove if $S \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and $s\neq \emptyset$ and S is bounded above

then $S$ has a maximum

Attempt By the completeness axiom $S$ has a supremum call it $s$.Assume $s \notin S$. Then $s>n$ for all $n \in S$.But $s-1$ is not an upper bound so $\exists n \in S$ such that $s-1<n$.Also since $n<s$, $\exists k \in S$  such that $k>n$.

$\implies$ $s-1<n<k<s$

$\implies k-n<1$ a contradiction

Is the contradiction the fact that we assumed that $k$ and $n$ are integers and since their difference is between $0$ and $1$ this is impossible? Also is $k-n<1$ because $n$ and $k$ have to be numbers in between $0$ and $1$, since $s-(s-1)=1$?

Comment: What is the well ordering principle? $\mathbb{Z}$ is not well ordered with the usual order.

Comment: @dcolazin sorry I meant completeness axiom ..changed

Comment: What do you mean by completeness axiom? Are you working in $\mathbb{R}$? If so: why can you assume $s \in \mathbb{Z}$? The proof is good btw. What do you mean by "if we picked different variables..."?

Comment: @dcolazin I really asked this question to see why there was a contradiction. Was it since we assumed $k,n$ were integers than since $k-n$ is not an integer it is a contradiction?

Comment: Actually, your proof looks pretty good. There is no harm in assuming that $s$ is an integer, since all elements of $S$ are integers. You don't need the integer $k.$ Since $s-1 < n < s,$ it follows that $0 < n < 1.$ Since there is no such $n,$ you are done

Comment: You *don't* assume $s \in \mathbb Z$ but you *prove* that it must be.  Yes, $\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb R$ so "the completeness axiom" says a bounded above subset (which $S$ is) has a $x =\sup S$.  The purpose of this proof is to prove that 1) $s$ *is* an integer (and there *is* harm in assuming it is an integer) and 2) That $s\in S$.  ANd hence it is a max.

Comment: OK. The supremum $s$ must be an integer. If it is not, then the greatest integer less than or equal to $s$ is an upper bound for $S$ since all elements in $S$ are integers, thus contradicting $s$ is the supremum. I wanted to address this last night, but had already turned off my computer and didn't want to get back on.

Comment: My first comment is proof that it is never wise to rush before bedtime. The correct phrasing at one point should be "since $s - 1 < n < s,$ it follows that $0 < s-n <1."$ Since $s-n$ is an integer, and there is no integer between $0$ and $1,$ you have your contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

The completeness axiom says that if $S \subset of \mathbb R$ is bounded above then a *real* $s =\sup S$ exists.

So if $S\subset \mathbb Z\subset \mathbb R$ is bounded above then there is a *real* $s =\sup S$.

The proof is to prove three things.

1) $s$ is actually an integer.

2) $s$ is a member of $S$

3) $s = \max S$.

Now the *definition* of $\sup S$ is that for any $y < s$ then $y$ *isn't* an upper bound of $S$. So $s-1 < s$ so $s-1$ is *not* an upper bound of $S$ which means there is an element $n\in S$ so that $n > s-1$.

So we have $s-1 < n \le s$.  We don't yet know that $s$ is an integer (that's our goal) but we do know that $n$ is an integer because $n\in S\subset \mathbb Z$.

With me so far?

Okay, our assumption (which is going to be proven false) is that $s \not \in S$.

That means $s-1 < n < s$.  That's seems okay, that means that $n$ is between two non-integers $s-1$ and $s$.  That can happen, right.

Except..... $n < s$.  So $n$ is also *not* an upper bound. So there is *another* $k \in S$ so that $s-1 < n < k\le s$.

And $k \in S \subset \mathbb Z$ so $k$ is an integer.

So we have two integers $n,k$ so that $s - 1 < n < k \le s$.  That's *not* okay.

That means $1 = s-(s-1)\ge k-(s-1) > k-n > n-n = 0$

Or,, to highlight the important stuff:  $0 < k-n < 1$.

SO you ask:

> Is the contradiction the fact that we assumed that k
>   and n are integers and since their difference is between 0 and 1 this is impossible?

Yes,  If $n,k$ are integers then so is $k-n$ but there are no integers between $0$ and $1$.

So that is the contradiction.

And

> Also is k−n<1 because n and k have to be numbers in between 0 and 1, since s−(s−1)=1?

Yes, that's right.

....

So we have contradicted our assumption that $s\not \in S$ so $s\in S$.

1) $s$ is an integer.

2) $s\in S$.

3) if $t \in S$ than $t \le s$ because $s$ is a an upper bound so

$s = \sup S = \max S$.

Comment: Thank you for this